# Error Expression must be a modifiable Ivalue In Insert Function (Binary Tree C++)

Tags: c++

I don't understand why it's error "Expression must be a modifiable Ivalue" in lines

```
temp->data.EN = x.EN;
temp->data.VN = x.VN;
```

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

typedef struct TD
{
    char VN[80];
    char EN[80];
};

typedef struct WORD
{
    TD data;
    WORD *left, *right;
};

WORD *t = NULL;

void InsertWord(TD x)
{
    WORD *temp, *parent, *current;
    temp = new WORD;
    temp->data.EN = x.EN;
    temp->data.VN = x.VN;
    temp->left = NULL;
    temp->right = NULL;
}
```

What is wrong in my code ?
Please help me !!!

Comment: you cant assign arrays like that, use `std::string` instead

Comment: Since this appears to be C not C++, you probably want to be using `strcpy` to copy the strings

Comment: @ChrisTurner not really C, it includes `<iostream>` and `<string>`, though not using them

Comment: It's a horrible mishmash of the two :/

Comment: You really don't need all of that code to show the issue.  A [mcve] could have been done easily --  `int main() { char x[10]; char y[10]; x = y; }`

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged C++, use [std::copy_n](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_n) since you can't copy arrays by simply assigning them to another.

```
std::copy_n(x.EN, 80, temp->data.EN);
std::copy_n(x.VN, 80, temp->data.VN);
```

Where the first, second and third parameters are the source, number of bytes and destination.